# How to update React State in Functional Component while fetching data using API

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to update the react state in functional component using API, However somehow it's not getting updated. I am not sure what is missing from my side. Can someone help what is missing in the below code snippet.

code

```
export default function Test(props) {
const [state, setState] = useState({
    data: []
  });

useEffect(() => {
  getConnectionUsers("Test")
  return () => {alert("component unmount");}
    }, [])
}

function getConnectionUsers(connection) {
    axios.get(URL).then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          console.log(response.data);  // This is showing correct data which is coming from API
          setState({...state ,data:response.data});
          console.log(state.data);    //Empty State is coming which means somehow state is not updated properly
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        alert(error)
      });
}
```

Comment: TL;DR React state updates are batched and asynchronous. React state is constant during the ***entire*** render cycle and only updated *between* render cycles. This means console logging state *right after* an enqueued updated will only ever log the *current* state from the *current* render cycle, not the enqueued state for the *next* render cycle. Use an `useEffect` hook with correct dependency to log state updates.

Comment: React this.setState, and useState does not make changes directly to the state object.

React this.setState, and React.useState create queues for React core to update the state object of a React component. So the process to update React state is asynchronous for performance reasons. That’s why changes don’t feel immediate.

Answer (score 1):

```
export default function Test(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    data: []
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    getConnectionUsers("Test")
    return () => {alert("component unmount");}
  }, []);

  function getConnectionUsers(connection) {
    axios.get(URL).then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          console.log(response.data);  // This is showing correct data which is coming from API
          setState({...state ,data:response.data});
          console.log(state.data);    //Empty State is coming which means somehow state is not updated properly
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        alert(error)
    });
  }  
}
```

You have to update your state in the lifecycle.
And you can't touch `useState` outside of the function.